# for loop over input lines

Tags: bash, text-processing, for

I have a file with a lot of lines like this

/item/pubDate=Sun, 23 Feb 2014 00:55:04 +010

If I execute this

```
echo "/item/pubDate=Sun, 23 Feb 2014 00:55:04 +010" | grep -Po "(?<=\=).*"

Sun, 23 Feb 2014 00:55:04 +010
```

I get the correct date (all in one line). Now I want to try this with a lot of dates in a xml file. I use this and it's ok.

```
xml2 < date_list | egrep "pubDate" | grep -Po "(?<=\=).*"
Fri, 22 Jan 2016 17:56:29 +0100
Sun, 13 Dec 2015 18:33:02 +0100
Wed, 18 Nov 2015 15:27:43 +0100
...
```

But now I want to use the date in a bash program and I get this output

```
for fecha in $(xml2 < podcast | egrep "pubDate" | grep -Po "(?<=\=).*"); do echo $fecha; done
    Fri,
    22
    Jan
    2016
    17:56:29
    +0100
    Sun,
    13
    Dec
    2015
    18:33:02
    +0100
    Wed,
    18
    Nov
    2015
    15:27:43
    +0100
```

I want the date output in one line (in variable fecha) how the first and second examples but I don't know how to do it.

Comment: `xml2 < date_list | egrep "pubDate" | grep -Po "(?<=\=).*" | while read fecha` ...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Do it this way instead:

```
while IFS= read -r fecha; do
    echo $fecha
done < <(xml2 < podcast | egrep "pubDate" | grep -Po "(?<=\=).*")
```

Bash will separate "words" to loop through by characters in the Internal Field Separator (`$IFS`). You can temporarily disable this behavior by setting `IFS` to nothing for the duration of the `read` command. The pattern above will always loop line-by-line.

`<(command)` makes the output of a command look like a real file, which we then redirect into our `read` loop.

```
$ while IFS= read -r line; do echo $line; done < <(cat ./test.input)
Fri, 22 Jan 2016 17:56:29 +0100
Sun, 13 Dec 2015 18:33:02 +0100
Wed, 18 Nov 2015 15:27:43 +0100
```

Comment: Is there a reason you turn `xml2 < podcast | egrep "pubDate" | grep -Po "(?<=\=).*"` into a "file" instead of piping its output to the `while` loop? If so, could you explain?

Comment: @gardenhead, [read this](http://serverfault.com/q/259339/313521), should answer the question in your comment there.

Answer (score 2):

```
xml2 < date_list | egrep "pubDate" | grep -Po "(?<=\=).*" \
| while read L
  do
    echo $L
  done
```

**read** breaks on lines, and doesn't split words unless asked.  :-)

However, tackling XML with regular expressions is bringing a knife to a gunfight.  It's very easy to construct valid XML that the above pipeline will either miss, or capture incorrectly.

If you deal with much XML, you really want to get comfortable with a SAX parser.